# Unable to install php5-dev package in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, apt

I am unable to install php5-dev package in ubuntu 12.10. I am getting the following on `sudo apt-get install php5-dev`:

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 E: Unable to locate package php5-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried installing php5-dev package in Ubuntu 12.10, and I didn't have any problems.  It installed fine.

[image]

I'm including images of my software sources, just so you can compare with yours.

[image]
[image]

I also suggest the you just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below prior to installing:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: yup! its working.. a lot of thanks for your answering **Mitch**.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when installing PHP or any other software.  I changed the update server and then it started working.

So, please try to change the update server if you get a similar error.

You can change the update server you are using by going to *System Settings > Software & updates*, and then change the "Download from" line to another server.